# how to determine whether a queue is empty in Simevents and do some actions based on this observation?

Tags: simevents

I want to model a queue with vacations. When the queue is empty, the server will have a period of vacation with certain distribution.(I can use use gate to block the server ) So I need to get the data of the number of entity in queue block. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry that I am not very familiar with Matlab.
Maybe I can write a discrete event-driven queue using customized block.
So if you know where to find these kinds of resources. It will be of great help as well.

Answer (score 0):

The "number of entities in the Queue" can be found in the 'Statistics' tab of the Queue's properties.

[image]

Enabling it (clicking it's checkbox) will enable the signal of interest on the block (#n) that can be connected to other Simulink blocks.

[image]

Connect the #n signal to "compare to constant" block to create a boolean signal that indicates if the queue is / is not empty.

[image]